# Differences between $('.class').on and $(document).on in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

What are the differences between

```
$(document).on('click', '.class', function() {
   //stuff
});
```

And

```
$(".class").on("click", function () {
    //stuff
});
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

Answer (score 6):

The first subscribes to the `.click` event in a *lively* manner. This means that it will listen for DOM changes and if in the future someone add an element with `class="class"` it will have the click handler attaced.

The second will subscribe to the click handler of all elements with `class="class"` at the moment you are making this subscription. If for example in the future you make an AJAX request and inject into your DOM an element with this class, it won't have the click event applied to it.

Comment: thanks @Darin Dimitrov..then where is the difference between

`$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".class").click(function(){
        //stuff
    });
});`
And 
`$(".class").on("click", function () {
    //stuff
});`

Comment: `$(document)` is likely less efficient than `$(".class")` as the class binding (`$(".class")`) limits the amount of click events the handler has to listen to.

Comment: @user3093439, there isn't any. `$(".class").click` is simply a wrapper for `$(".class").on("click"` See the [docs on click](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

Comment: Then if i use AJAX request and inject into my dom i have to use `$(document).on` ?

Comment: Depends where and what html your injecting. If your not sure you could maybe open a new question with the specifics.